# It could be alive,

Tags: riddle

> It could be alive,
>
> but it is not
>
> Could be any color,
>
> Depends on the one you got.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> a mirror?

It could be alive,

> if it is reflecting a living thing (animals are often subjected to the mirror test and some believe they are being confronted by another animal)

but it is not

> because a mirror only shows a reflection

Could be any color,
Depends on the one you got.

> If you wear red, the mirror will reflect the red for example.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> water?
>
>  As it can flow and move which makes it seem alive but it's not.
>  Transparent and reflective so reflects any color.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad/vague...  Is this

> An LED?

if it was alive

> (/live) then you'd know what colour it was

Could also be:

> a wire, a dead animal, etc...  Maybe add a line or two?